# How do I control Google Search Results display properties?

Tags: css

I am putting the finishing touches on a customized Google Search for a [site](http://www.dayofservice.org) and need a little assistance tweaking the header on the results page.

I was able to manage the spacing of the results content with:

```
#results4   { width: 620px; padding: 20px;  }
```

However you will notice that the top row of information

> Results 1 - 10 for search...

runs off the right side of the content area.

I tried using the following code, but it didn't help:

```
.t  td  { align:left; }
```

I also tried margin-right and padding but those didn't work either. what is the best way to get that content to move over into the content area?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style the `iframe` that gets rendered on your page like this:

```
#cse-search-results iframe { width: 620px; }
```

Tested in Firefox and IE8, should be fine in other browsers too.

Comment: Excellent. With a margin-left:20px it looks just right. Thank you.